# In Java source code, what does "Offloaded for" mean?

Tags: java, java-7, jls

In the `java.util` source code for `HashMap`, there are refactored out methods `putForNullKey` and `getForNullKey` with the comment:

```
/**
 * Offloaded version of put for null keys
 */
private V putForNullKey(V value) {
```

What does "offloaded" mean in this context? Refactored, or something more subtle?

Comment: I've never heard this word in an OOP or Java context.  The first place it comes to mind is in [TCP offloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine), which allows the CPU to off-load some work to the NIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means nothing special. They just decided to have separate code for the put-logic if the key is `null`, and they separated that code from the non-null code into method `putForNullKey`.

When you look at `put` you will find the if-clause that checks for null-keys and - if so - delegates to `putForNullKey`:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);

    // ... here comes the put code for non-null-keys
}
```

Comment: Good explanation. I still wouldn't have used the term "Offloaded". I think "Special case" makes more sense, personally.